# Update SQL Server database via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, upsert

I am working with Entity Framework in a C# project to read/write data from/to a SQL Server database.

Until now, I read the data and did some calculations. Now I want to write the results to the database. What I essentially have is a list of `[ID, Date, Value]` tuples.

The update logic should be like an UPSERT, that is, an `INSERT` should occur, if in the target table for the combination of `ID` and `Date` no row is present. An `UPDATE` should be done, if the combination of `ID` and `Date` is already present in the target table.

Let's say I have ~1000 records in my result list. If I loop through the list and execute the UPSERT logic for each item in the list, that would result in ~1000 `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements. I think that there should be a more efficient way to do this.

Hence, my two questions are:

1. How can I implement the described UPSERT logic without generating a separate SQL statement for each result item?
2. More generally: how would such an UPSERT logic look like in C# using Entity Framework?

Comment: EF keeps track of the entities given to your code. So generally speaking, it already knows what to do with the entities that you update or add to its DbSets. SaveChanges should already do what you ask. But without code is not clear what problem do you really have. Please show your upsert logic.

Comment: If you have 1000 records you shouldn't be using an ORM in the first place. ORMs are meant to map entities to tables, not act as a replacement for SQL. They are unsuitable for reporting, bulk operations and ETL jobs like this one.

Comment: If you want to update a target table with 1000 new records, the easy and fast way is to insert the data into a temporary or staging table (eg using SqlBulkCopy) and perform either a MERGE between source and target or execute an `UPDATE` followed by an INSERT using as source the joined tables. This can be 1000 times faster than having the ORM execute 1000 RPC calls to execute 1000 queries

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment to ask if you have access to stored procedures, or if you have had other considerations, so apologies in advance.

Try a delete where `[ID, Date]` for all records you are 'upserting' and then a bulk insert. You wouldn't necessary need Entity Framework poco actions, but it would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for performance, you want to generate a SQL Server `MERGE` statement, which does the `INSERT` and/or `UPDATE` as a single action.  I don't believe that this is built into Entity Framework, unfortunately, but there are fairly straightforward workarounds.  For one, see here:

https://www.flexlabs.org/2018/02/adding-upsert-support-for-entity-framework-core

Comment: MERGE doesn't do that in a single action, it's not even atomic. Yes, it's somewhat more convenient to write but not faster by updating the target from a source table followed by an INSERT

Comment: I would have expected that a MERGE from the client causes one round-trip and one index lookup to happen as opposed to an UPDATE followed by an INSERT which causes two round trips and two index lookups.  However, it seems that that is not in fact the case.  Thank you for the clarification.  Hopefully SQL Server will come up with a proper solution to this problem that doesn't have the performance penalty...